# How to have a separate output window in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

[If you look at the picture inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1IgQ.png) You'll see the output window is at the bottom in PyCharm so is there a way to get the PyCharm output window at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do both -- separate window to pinned to top:

To make a *separate* window, choose floating mode from the tools menu (little gear symbol upper right of the output windows).  There you can move it anywhere you like.

But to just move it to the top. simply open the same tools menu and choose "Move To..." and it'll go where you want without making it a separate window.  Your choice!

Comment: Thank you @JLH! That works. I'll make this as answer after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Top" option, this will move it to the top of the screen.
[image: img]

Comment: Thank you @kstullich! But my question is I want a separate windows in PyCharm :)

Comment: No worries, then JLH answer is what you're looking for. @KarthikSrivijay